# SpresenseのGNSS測定周期を変更することは可能ですか？

Tags: spresense, gps

Sony Spresenseを用いたGNSSトラッカーを作成しています。

ドキュメントには、GNSS取得周期が1Hzであると記載されていますが、10Hzまで周期を大きくすることはできないのでしょうか？

また、現時点では10Hzできない場合、今後将来的に10HzでGNSS測定できるように開発を進める予定はございますでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

ioctlのCXD56_GNSS_IOCTL_SET_OPE_MODEで測位周期を変更できます。

```c
  /* Set the GNSS operation interval. */

  set_opemode.mode     = 1;     /* Operation mode:Normal(default). */
  set_opemode.cycle    = 1000;  /* Position notify cycle(msec step). */

  ret = ioctl(fd, CXD56_GNSS_IOCTL_SET_OPE_MODE, (uint32_t)&set_opemode);
```

デフォルトはcycle=1000(1Hz)になっていますが、この値を変えると測位周期を変えられます。

私もSpresenseでトラッカーを自作しましたが、ベストエフォートで動作しているようで、
500(2Hz), 250(4Hz), 200(5Hz) と指定すると、その周期で測位値を取得できました。
(4Hz, 5Hz を指定したときに、高速移動中だとややドリフト軌跡が目立つかも)

試しに100(10Hz) を指定してみてその周期をみると200msec間隔になっているので、
結果的に5Hzが限界な気がします。